# $U\cap W=\{0\}$ for all vector spaces?

Tags: linear-algebra

Imagine I am dealing with a vector space V whose subspaces are W and U. Is it true that $U\cap W=\{0\}$?

I have been answering some exercises which do not define if $U\cap W=\{0\}$. Is this true for every Vector space?

> Let $U,W$ be the subspaces of a vector space $V$. The map of $U\times W: \to V$ is given by: $(u,w)\to u-v$. Show that the kernel is isomorphic to $U\cap W$.

If you do not consider $U\cap W=\{0\}$. How do you answer this question?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What if $V=W=U$?

Comment: in your update you ask a new and different question. i suggest you make a seperate post for that and include some of the attempts that you made to solve the problem

Comment: I mean, as enticing as the idea of having an easy exercise may be, what would be the point of phrasing it in this way, if that were the case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. For example, if $U=W\neq\{0\}$, then $U\cap W\neq \{0\}$

---

After the edit:

Your question is now completely different. You now have to show that the kernel of the mapping (let's call it $f$) defined as $(u, w)\mapsto u-v$ is isomorphic to $U\cap V$. To do that, first look at what the kernel is by definition. It is the set

$$\{(u,v)\in U\times V| f(u, v)=0\}$$

Now, clearly $f(u,v)=0$ if and only if $u=v$ (because $f(u,v)=0\iff u-v=0\iff u=v$). So, each element in $\ker f$ is equal to $(x,x)\in U\times V$. From that, you can probably see a natural mapping into $U\cap V$.

Comment: Please check my update.

Comment: @PedroGomes I did and I updated my answer.

Comment: It has been very helpful, thanks for your insight!

Comment: @PedroGomes You are very welcome. Good luck with your further studies!

Answer (score 2):

No this is not true. The simplest way to see this if you choose $W=U=V$ and $V$ has dimension at least $1$.

It is also possible to find less trivial counterexamples where $V=\mathbb R^3$, and $U,V$ are distinct two-dimensional subspaces.

Comment: Please check my update.